# How can I use PHP arrays in queries?

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

Hi guys I have this query:

```
$URLA=implode("','",$Array);
$Data=$connection->prepare("SELECT Category,ID FROM SITES WHERE URL IN('".$Array."') AND Email=:Email ORDER BY Category DESC");
$Data->bindValue(':URL', $URL);
$Data->bindValue(':Email', $Email);
$Data->execute();
```

This code give this error:
 Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens.
How can I solve this problem?
Note that Array is a variable that comes out from a while loop.And contain more that one variable.
I tryied bind this array like this:

```
$Data->bindValue(':Array', $Array);
```

But this didn't worked :'(

Comment: `URL IN('".$Array."')` that should be `$URLA`

Comment: you're also not using `:URL` in the query. I hope you weren't intending on using this for `WHERE URL`.

Comment: @ Funk Forty Niner nono, because the implode will do the array like: 1','2,' so with ' 'it will be '1','2'

Comment: whats inside `$Array` ???

Comment: @Abdulla Nilam just 1 and 2

Comment: like this `array(1, 2);`

Comment: yes, and with the implode it will become like: WHERE URL IN ('1','2')

Comment: is `URL` integer field?

Comment: @Abdulla Nilam the array can contain also string, for example WHERE URL  IN ('1','2','ABC')

Answer (score 0):

As you [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48026808/php-how-to-use-arrays-in-querys#comment83023512_48026808), your array looks like this `array(1,2,'ABC');`,

try this

```
$URLA= implode("', '", $array); # wrapping with single quote 

$Data=$connection->prepare("SELECT Category,ID FROM SITES WHERE URL IN(".$URLA.") AND Email=:Email ORDER BY Category DESC");
// $Data->bindValue(':URL', $URL); Seems no longer needed.
$Data->bindValue(':Email', $Email);
```

Or

```
$URLA= implode("', '", $array); # wrapping with single quote 

$Data=$connection->prepare("SELECT Category,ID FROM SITES WHERE URL IN(:url) AND Email=:Email ORDER BY Category DESC");
$Data->bindValue(':URL', $URLA);
$Data->bindValue(':Email', $Email);
```

Comment: Could I bind the array for avoid SQL Injection?

Comment: you can  use this `$Data->bindValue(':URL', $URL);` with `IN(:url)`

Comment: @user9154057 check the [edit now](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48026972/revisions) and check this [answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)